# jackson unable to unmarshal json string

Tags: jackson2

I am using Jackson to Marshall Java object to Json format, there is no issue in marshaling but during marshaling Jackson throws exception

> Exception

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Problem deserializing 'setterless' property 'tradeCharges': get method returned null
```

> Java

```
    public static Object getObject(String filePath, Class clazz) {
        Object object = null;
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); // setting this true returns null object.
e
            object = mapper.readValue(new File(filePath), Sts.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return object;
    }
```

The object which i am trying to marshal unmarshall is returned from third party external jar.

How Jackson process marshaling and unmarshaling. Should jackson be able to unmarshall when it's able to marshall ?

The java object structure is complex and the json object generated from java is in MB.

Comment: Could you post example `JSON` payload and show `POJO` class?

Comment: Pojo class is huge, is there any specific part i can share ?

Comment: Related with `tradeCharges` and `setterless`. You probably have some kind of `NPE`.